# Is it possible to use .NET assemblies In Access 2003?

Tags: .net, ms-access

Is it possible?

If it is possible, how do I do it and is it problematic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access 2003 support COM so you should be able to use COM interop to access them I would have thought. There seems to be video here that [purports](http://whitepapers.zdnet.com/abstract.aspx?docid=84974) to do this.